# dynamically load aframe entities

Tags: javascript, aframe

I´m building an aframe application, which can dynamically load s from a webservice based on user interaction. These entities are available in text-form.
What I need is a way to inject these into the aframe DOM, so that the entities are immediately visible.
Is there a way to accomplish this?
Neither Google nor the Aframe documentation could help me yet.

Comment: Creating entities dinamically works similar to traditional DOM manipulation using `document.createElement` / `setAttribute` / `appendChild` There’s a section in the docs devoted to it https://aframe.io/docs/0.7.0/introduction/javascript-events-dom-apis.html

Comment: yes I saw this one. But as far as I can tell, this creates DOM elements one by one. but when I have a nested entity like

  `<a-entity>
    <a-sphere></a-sphere>
    <a-light></a-light>
  </a-entity>`

is there a way to handle this without parsing it, and creating the DOM elements seperately?

Comment: Sure, you can. `el.innerHMTL = “<a-entity> <a-sphere></a-sphere> <a-light></a-light> </a-entity>“` That’s how regular DOM works not specific to A-Frame

Comment: Thank you Diego! I didn´t assume that A-Frame handles innerHTML correctly - but it does exactly what I need. I guess i was blind on this eye.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create and configure the entities individually using `document.createElement` / `setAttribute` / `appendChild`. There's a [section in the docs](https://aframe.io/docs/0.7.0/introduction/javascript-events-dom-apis.html) devoted to it.

You can also manipulate the innerHTML value directly:

```
el.innerHMTL = "<a-entity> <a-sphere></a-sphere> <a-light></a-light> </a-entity>"
```

None of the above it is A-Frame specific, you just use the regular DOM APIs to compose your scene